# Trigger the execution of packaged code?

Tags: postinstall

We know we can run a post-install script but if the script fails, it will fail the package install. What other ways can we trigger the execution of packaged code, perhaps manually after the package install has been completed?

If any documentation about this, it would be really appriciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place in my view is a custom config page that customers can access via the Configure link on the Installed Packages page:

[image]

That has all of our post install functionality/settings available for the user to view and update, and is easy to point them to. Since it is part of the package, it can access all the packages code such as Protected Settings, so you can expose those pieces there as well.

You just have to set it on the package screen in the packaging org as a custom 
link.

Here is a [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading.htm) to the package overview

And specifically, [details](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=develop_documentation.htm&type=5) about the Config Link

Comment: can you post any documentation link so that I can understand more about it.

Comment: configure custom link is not an automated scheduler right but in post install script will do automated scheduler that way client no need to do anything specifically to schedule a job but in configure client has to do scheduling right.

Do you know any other option?

Comment: We just have a button they can click that will schedule the job...that way they can control which user it is scheduled under

Comment: other than this don't we have any other options?

Comment: I am trying to create custom link for Configure it is not showing Configure in installed package page.

Should we able create custom link for unmanaged packages?

Should we need post install script for Custom Configure link? with out any involvement of post install script can we use this Configure?

Please answer for all these questions.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to add the link via the Custom Links section under Home in setup. I think you can use them in unmanaged packages (it's definitely available there at least)
You should be able to add a  button to the page that the config page links to that can run the same code as the Install Package would

Answer (score 0):

The only other option than the already mentioned custom package post-install page (which I think is an elegant way to do it) which I know would be to expose the post-install code as a [global class and method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm). That comes with some limitations however (e.g. the signature of the method can never be changed) and should be considered carefully.
That way you could trigger the code via the debug console by using one line of code.